# Vue js keep previous element open using the same select

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

this is my first Vue.js project and I'm using it via CDN just to list some data from DB. I have nested `v-for` to list users and their posts. Inside of each primary `v-for` I have a `select` loading posts titles with another `v-for`. When I select a title I want to open the corresponding post.

It works almost 100%. My problem is that when I select a new option (title) in a second user, the first post that was open is closing. So it alternates between one and another.

I created an element using another `v-for` to list all posts but created a condition to display only the corresponding one with its title.

And I tried to create some other condition along with the existing ones, using `true` if open but it didn't work. Is it possible to reuse the same element for this case?

I remember it was easy to do that using filters when I worked with angularjs. Is there anything similar in this case?

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>

    <div class="tour-options-select">
        <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown"
                v-model="selected" class="tour-options-dropdown"
                @change="showTour = selected">

            <option v-for="(tour, key) in item.tours" :key="key" :value="tour.tourID">
                {{ tour.title }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    // here each post is listed by selecting its title
    <div v-for="(tour, key) in item.tours" v-if="showTour == tour.tourID" class="tour-suggestions">
        <div class="tour-list">
          <div class="tour-list-title">
             <p>{{ tour.title }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tour-list-description">
             <p>
                {{ tour.description }}
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tour-list-pics">
             <ul class="pics-list">
                <li v-for="image in tour.images">
                   <div class="pics-list-image-container"
                  v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/tours/'+image.image + ')' }"
                  @click="openModal = true, showModal(image.image)"></div>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div @click="showTour = false" class="close-suggestions">
          <span>X</span>
       </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: remove the `showTour` idea, its singular and toggle something on the object itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: {},
      toursObj: {},
      hosters: [{
          id: "0",
          name: "name0",
          lastname: "lastname0",
          tours: [{
              tourID: "tourID0_0",
              title: "title0_0",
              description: "description0_0",
            },
            {
              tourID: "tourID0_1",
              title: "title0_1",
              description: "description0_1",
            },
            {
              tourID: "tourID0_1",
              title: "title0_1",
              description: "description0_1",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "name1",
          lastname: "lastname1",
          tours: [{
              tourID: "tourID1_0",
              title: "title1_0",
              description: "description1_0",
            },
            {
              tourID: "tourID1_1",
              title: "title1_1",
              description: "description1_1",
            },
            {
              tourID: "tourID1_1",
              title: "title1_1",
              description: "description1_1",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>

    <div class="tour-options-select">
        <select :id="'select-suggestions' + item.id" name="tour-options-dropdown" v-model="selected[item.id]" class="tour-options-dropdown">
            <option v-for="(tour, key) in item.tours" :key="key" :value="tour.tourID">
                {{ tour.title }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div v-if="toursObj[selected[item.id]]"  class="tour-suggestions">
        <div class="tour-list">
          <div class="tour-list-title">
             <p>{{ toursObj[selected[item.id]].title }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tour-list-description">
             <p>
                {{ toursObj[selected[item.id]].description }}
             </p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <button type="button" @click="closeTour(item.id)">
          <span>X</span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
  created() {
    this.setToursObj();
  },
  methods: {
    setToursObj() {
      const TOURS_OBJ = {};
      this.hosters.forEach(hoster => {
        hoster.tours.forEach(tour => {
          TOURS_OBJ[tour.tourID] = tour;
        });
      });
      this.toursObj = TOURS_OBJ;
    },
    closeTour(id) {
      this.selected[id] = undefined;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Great approach! It's almost working for complete. It just opens the same post as many times as the number of user's posts.

Comment: Don't mind. I just fixed the template. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to set a default value in select? I'm trying based on the `v-model` but it's not working.